How to create a text mask with a reverse color of the SVG background using CSS?
I have an SVG image as the background-image for the footer of my webpage. The logo text appears over this background, and its color needs to adapt to the background's light or dark sections.
On large screens, the logo text falls entirely on the white part of the background, so a black text works fine. On mobile screens, it appears over the dark part of the image, so I switch the text color to white, which also works. The issue arises with intermediate screen sizes, where the logo text might overlap both light and dark areas of the background. This causes parts of the text to blend into the background, making it unreadable.
I would like to create a solution where the SVG acts as a mask for the text, automatically changing the logo text color (e.g., from black to white) based on the background it overlaps. How can I achieve this effect?
What are some effective techniques or CSS properties that would help solve this issue?
Here is a simple fiddle, the SVG is set as background-image in the original code.
I have tried to use something like mix-blend-mode but it's not what I am looking for:
      footer {
        background-image: url("../assets/images/mountains.svg");
        z-index: 0;
      }
    
      .logo {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    
      .logo::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "Relaps";
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        color: white;
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
      }

This is what I would archieve:


It would be better to post the svg here. if it is within the coepen that nobody is legally allowed to write an answer here using it.

PS instead of using an image and use it as background, I would use a background-image which would be semantically correct and then simply use the mix-blend-mode: difference on the h2.

Can you include the text as a text node in the SVG instead as an h2 outside of the SVG?

@tacoshy I've add a shared link to the SVG here on SO might it work for legally write an answer using it?

@tacoshy so wait you would use the background-image on the footer or what?

mix-blend-mode: difference should work fine, but the overlay needs to be opaque (monochrome black and white in this case) due to how alpha blending works with these blend modes.
Please excuse the poor linear gradient excuse for a forestscape.


#a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(22deg, #111 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
  font-size: 40pt;
}
#a h1 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
<div id="a">
  <h1>Relaps</h1>
</div>




I was a bit confused about the overlay, the issue was that the SVG background was transparent so by using the mix-blend-mode when the text was on the page background it was drawn withing a black square, btw by making the SVG background monochrome it does work pretty well.
